# How to submit a specific form without making the contents of both go away?

Tags: javascript, html

I think I see why I was confused.  The contents of the specific form is submitted but the page reloads.  This causes the the contents of both to disappear making me think that it submitted the contents of both.  Thanks!(Also correct me if I'm wrong)

Answered question:

I made to forms on a page. But the submit buttons effect both forms.(by this I mean make both inputs go away)  How can I make it only submit to a specific one? I tried doing these,

```
<Input type="button" value="submit" onClick="document.form.sumbit.formName">
<Input type="button" value="submit" onClick="document.sumbit.formName">
<Input type="button" value="submit" onClick="document.formName.submit">
```

But those didn't work.  It would be a great help if anyone could tell me how to make it specify to a specific form!

```
<body>

    <FORM name="personal">
       Name:<Input type="text"><br>
       E-mail:<Input type="text"><br>
       <Input type="submit" value="submit">
    </FORM>
    <hr>
    <FORM name="preferences">
       Favourite food:<Input type="text"><br>
       Favourite drink:<Input  type="text"><br>
       <Input type="submit" value="submit">
    </FORM>
</body>
```

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript, by assigning id's

Comment: Each submit button will only submit the form it belongs to. So you don't even need JavaScript (unless what you're looking for is an ajax submit...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with JavaScript:

```
    <FORM name="personal" id="personal">
       Name:<Input type="text"><br>
       E-mail:<Input type="text"><br>
       <Input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit_personal">
    </FORM>
    <hr>
    <FORM name="preferences" id="preferences">
       Favourite food:<Input type="text"><br>
       Favourite drink:<Input  type="text"><br>
       <Input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit_preferences">
    </FORM>


<script>
function submit_preferences(){
    document.getElementById("Preferences").submit();
    }
function submit_personal(){
    document.getElementById("Personal").submit();
    }

</script>
```

Actually, here's an edit. I tested your original code and it works fine. I think you might be wanting to open it in a new window or without closing the current window. To do that, either use AJAX, or you can just add `target="_blank"` to the original, like this:

```
    <FORM name="personal" id="personal" target="_blank">
       Name:<Input type="text"><br>
       E-mail:<Input type="text"><br>
       <Input type="submit" value="submit">
    </FORM>
    <hr>
    <FORM name="preferences" id="preferences" target="_blank">
       Favourite food:<Input type="text"><br>
       Favourite drink:<Input  type="text"><br>
       <Input type="submit" value="submit">
    </FORM>
```

Comment: So it is affecting only one form but the page is reloading making both disappear?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can test it out with `action="google.com"` in one of the `<form>` tags

Answer (score 3):

```
document.forms['preferences'].submit()
```

I'm not sure that we're getting at what you're asking for, though. Posting either form will round-trip the whole page because, well, that's just how HTTP works. If you want to post one form asynchronously while the other one stays put, you'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: I think you can add `target="_blank"` to the `<form>` tag to make it open in a new window

Comment: So it is affecting only one form but the page is reloading making both disappear?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you,

```
    <FORM name="personal">
       Name:<Input type="text"><br>
       E-mail:<Input type="text"><br>
       <Input type="submit" name="form2" value="submit">
    </FORM>
    <hr>
    <FORM name="preferences">
       Favourite food:<Input type="text"><br>
       Favourite drink:<Input  type="text"><br>
       <Input type="submit" name="form2" value="submit">
    </FORM>
</body>
```

Comment: Also please name your form fields for best experience. In PHP or any other language you will probably need these name values to identify fields. But sure in PHP you need them :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```